# Two Sum on LeetCode not returning as expected

Tags: python

I am doing LeetCode , but however when I tried to submit my code . it says it is wrong when my local python file the result is looking for `9`

Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

Example:

Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1].

```
class Solution(object):
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            for j in range(len(nums)):
                if nums[i] == nums[j]:
                    pass
                elif nums[i]+nums[j] == target:
                    print(i,j)


a = Solution()
a.twoSum([2,7,11,15],9)
```

Comment: `return` instead of `print` perhaps?

Comment: Accumulate all pairs that meet the criteria in a list then return the list.

Comment: I am returning ```return [nums[i], nums[j]] ``` which gives me the value , but if I use ```return [i,j]``` it fails too which the second return is my index , but I dont know if it's works locally

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it wants you to return a list with the indices of the two items that add up to the target, but you're printing it to the console. Try changing `print(i,j)` to `return [i, j]`. Also remember that you shouldn't submit your last 2 lines, they are only for local testing.

`:rtype: List[int]` is the hint telling you that it expects a return value of a List containing ints.

This should solve your immediate issue and solve the example test case, there are other small issues which you'll hopefully figure out after.